# Load External Content into div using AJAX not working?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to load external content into div tag, but its shown an error like this " Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

But when i run in firefox its running partially. please suggest me the possible solution.

***HTML***

```
<div id="page">
    <h2 align="center">Welcome</h2>     
 </div>
```

***AJAX***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

          $('#1').click(function(){
            $("#page").load('content.html');
          });

          $('#2').click(function(){
           $("#page").load('content1.html');
          });

          $('#3').click(function(){
           $("#page").load('content2.html');
          });           

          $('#4').click(function(){
           $("#page").load('content3.html');
          });
    });             
</script>
```

Comment: Show us the rest of your code.